# Ideas for a present to my topology teacher

Tags: algebraic-topology, soft-question

Tomorrow is the my final lecture in my favorite course, algebraic topology. I want to give a present to my prof. as a keepsake, something along the lines of this [image: Klein hat]

only something I can make due tomorrow and without knowledge in sewing. Any ideas?

Comment: Mobius strips and various knots should be relatively easy to make. Some pipe cleaners could work to exhibit (representatives of a) multiplication in a fundamental group.

Comment: I have seen a youtube video where a woman teaches how to knit a Möbius strip hoodie/scarf/something. Maybe that will do?

Comment: that's knitting, btw.

Answer (score 6):

Does it have to be something you made yourself? If not, how about the proverbial [donut and coffee cup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aMug_and_Torus_morph.gif)? You could attach a card that said something like "sorry, I'm not sure which is which", or put them in separate boxes with the coffee cup labeled "donut" and the donut labeled "coffee cup".

Comment: this is smart one!

Comment: Great suggestion!

Answer (score 3):

Get a bagel, and cut it so you have two intersecting hoops. While it's not really a keepsake (as its food), it'd be tasty if you put some cream cheese on.

How to video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dN8AwGUaqDA

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!